# How to not print types in Julia?

Tags: printing, types, julia

If I have an array of numbers:

```
a = [1,2,3]
```

and print it, I get

```
[1,2,3]
```

but if I have an array of, say, Tuples:

```
b = [(1,2),(3,)]
```

when I print it I get:

```
Tuple{Int64,Vararg{Int64}}[(1,2),(3,)]
```

How to avoid printing the types?

Comment: I don't think it's possible without writing your own function to print.

Comment: @TimothéePoisot is right, you can't suppress that output. The easiest thing is probably to write your own type that wraps the object you need, and write your own method for `Base.show` of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be suppressed.

```
julia> b = [(1,2), (3,)]
2-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Vararg{Int64}},1}:
 (1,2)
 (3,)
```

Maybe the type is being printed to show you that you are including a `Vararg` type.

If you want an output without the message, you can go ahead and write a wrapper for [Base.show](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/master/base/show.jl)