# Is there a way to print without datatype info in Julia?

Tags: julia, radix

For example:

```
julia> print([1,"2"]) 

Any[1, "2"]
```

I was expecting `[1, "2"]` to be the console output

This gets ugly for complex datatypes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to not print types in Julia?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536437/how-to-not-print-types-in-julia)

Comment: You probably want to be using `@printf`.

Comment: Not possible to avoid the involvement of datatypes using @printf i guess. could you pls give an example if otherwise?

Comment: You could try something like `print("[" * join(map(repr, [1,"2"]), ", ") * "]")`

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use this ugly workaround:

```bash
import Base.show
import Base.repr

function show(io::IO, a::Array{Any,1})
  print("[")
  first = true
  for i in a
    print(first ? "":",", repr(i))
    first = false 
  end
  print("]")
end

function repr(a::Array{Any,1})
  ret = "["
  first = true
  for i in a
    ret *= (first ? "":",") * repr(i)
    first = false 
  end
  ret *= "]"
end


julia> print([1,"2"])
[1,"2"]

julia> print([1,"2","t", [1,"2"]])
[1,"2","t",[1,"2"]]
```